# date-input-polyfill in Safari 5.1.7 browser

Tags: html, date

I have written a simple HTML file. In that in have included input `<date>` element which will not be supported by IE, Safari.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Date Polyfill</title>
</head>
<body>
    Date Field : 
    <input type="date" name="polyfill-date" id="polyfill-date">

</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to make it work in Safari, So I have included date-input-polyfill by using "npm install --save date-input-polyfill" dependency in my project.

after that, I included this script tag in my HTML file.

```
<script src="node_modules/date-input-polyfill/date-input-polyfill.dist.js"></script>
```

then the date filed worked in IE but not in Safari.

The main aim is not to depend on any library like datepicker or anything. I just wanted to create a polyfill / fallback.

I am working in window 10 with Safari 5.1.7.

Kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: Safari 5.1.7 is too old to be useful. What do you need it for? Is it a requirement from higher up?

Comment: It is not working in Safari browser which is installed in windows but perfectly working in IOS Safari

Comment: Exactly! So to solve this, you should arrange access to a Mac.